# The tools version "12.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "2.0", "3.5", "4.0". (MSB4132) (SteamTrade)

Tags: c#, xamarin

I was editing a SteamBot and i finally finished it. However when I debugged it, (Im using Xamarin), this error came up

> Error MSB4132: The tools version "12.0" is unrecognized. Available
>   tools versions are "2.0", "3.5", "4.0". (MSB4132) (SteamTrade).

I tried changing the "12.0" in SteamTrade.csproj to those values "2.0", "3.5", "4.0" however they just bring up other errors.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzzln.png

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install the [MSBuild Tools 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760). In this version (12.0), the version number matches the Visual Studio version number.

The `LogStandardErrorAsError` parameter is only available in version 12.0 and above.

See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to download and install build tools separately from Visual Studio.  Version 15 supports building C# 7 projects.  Download Link: https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15